# Stopping a v-icon in header slot in v-data-table from spinning

Tags: vuetify.js

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikecole/pen/zLNKbG)

In the CodePen sample I added a second `v-icon` to the header template. If you sort the column, you can see that both icons spin, when I want the second one to not spin. How can I mark it so it doesn't spin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it via css. Here is updated codepen

https://codepen.io/aldarund/pen/yqgVgy

```
...
<v-icon class='no-rotate' small>filter_list</v-icon>
...
.v-datatable thead th.column.sortable.active.desc .no-rotate {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Now to find out how to stop the column from sorting if you click on that extra icon.

Comment: @MikeCole add @ click.stop to icon. I have updated codepen in asnwer, u can check

Comment: Thanks! I just added a bounty and will award it when allowed.